# How do I add only the current month and year to the header of an Excel workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, headers

I need to input the current year into my header and add the sheet name as the day (e.g., 2/[Tab]/[YYYY]). Is this possible? I know the **Insert Date** option puts a dynamic date into the header, but I need to be able to control the month manually if possible.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One way is to use a VBA routine and you can set the header sections however you wish.  The macro could be either run manually, or be triggered by a `Workbook_BeforePrint` event, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it using VBA.

First Enter the below formula into `CELL A1`, this can be changed to any cell you want, just ensure you change the reference point in the macro part.

```
=DAY(TODAY())&"/"&MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&"/"&YEAR(TODAY())
```

It will create your dynamic date and sheet name combo.

Then put the below into a module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

It will take the date combo and set it into your header before printing.

It should also come into effect before you view the print preview.

Comment: Peter, I'll definitely try that out! I assume this wouldn't work if the file is primarily used in the online Excel app?

Comment: @rtinstruct let me know how you get on with it, as for online im not sure as ive never used online services for excel

Comment: Why not obtain the sheet name directly using native VBA methods?